# Entity Framework Migrations Issue: DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I can enable migrations, but i cannot update DB or add a migration. When i try to disable-migrations to then re-enable i get 
"The term 'disable-migrations' is not recognized ", I have tried removing the package and reinstalling running as admin, changing App.config lines.
  I have the same issue at my work pc and my home one, Ive read a lot of posts on here and the suggestions have not fixed my issue.   no matter what i do when it comes to modifying I always get this error (adding migration,updating db etc)

```
PM> add-migration TTT
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section connectionString. (C:\Users\bern4rdo\Desktop\BasicEntityApp\tmp9260.tmp line 8)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForAssembly(Assembly assemblyHint, Type contextTypeHint)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext(Type contextType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..ctor()
   at BasicEntityApp.Migrations.Configuration..ctor() in C:\Users\bern4rdo\Desktop\BasicEntityApp\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 10
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration(Type contextType, String configurationTypeName, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The type initializer for ***'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception.**
PM>*
```

I have checked the file it references in

C:\Users\bern4rdo\Desktop\BasicEntityApp\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 10

which line 10 is the conneciton string. I have included the app config file below but if I'm able to get a good direction on what to do next, i would appreciate it a lot. I have ruled out things like permissions, ive tried different servers etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionString>
    <add name="SalesContext" connectionstring="DataSource=BERNARDO\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalogue=BasicEntityApp; trusted security=true; trustedserverCertificate=false;" providername="System.Data.sqlClient" />
  </connectionString>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>

    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config section is incorrectly named `<connectionString>` when it should in fact be `<connectionStrings>`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SalesContext" connectionstring="DataSource=BERNARDO\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalogue=BasicEntityApp; trusted security=true; trustedserverCertificate=false;" providername="System.Data.sqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Tried both. Initially had it as connectionStrings :/ will try it again >.<